# How to change the default spinner-layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I created with Android Studio 1.0 a new project and added a spinner. But the result doesn't look very understandable. It's not clear enough that the spinner is a clickable object. It shows only the top element and a small arrow down. [My default Spinner](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/spinner6r0qoz97f4.png)

I've implemented the spinner the way the developer-page from android describes.
How can I change it to something, that looks more like [this](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/androidspinnerrnw280asm7.png).

I've tried things like setting the background color, but in the result the little arrow disappears.

How is it possible, that my default layout looks so different from the declared one by developer.android.com?

Comment: the second picture is not accessable please change

Comment: I've changed the link - it should be visible now. I would be happy about every different looking design.

Comment: You don't want it looking like that. That's Android 2.3.

Comment: ok. But why is it not looking like the standard design: [link](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/androidspinnerrnw280asm7.png). The underline would be nice and looks more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case you can create your own custom spinner or set some selector to it. For example: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107